# Need to match condition in first column, then match condition from second column to display that rows information

Tags: excel, vba

I've set up a database for locating inventory quicker. But now I'm having problems trying to figure how to show the inventory from another row if the ID in the first column is the same but the ID in the second column is what I need to look for.

```
Dim BlendRow As Integer
Dim srchRow As Range
Dim LPNRow As Integer
Dim nxtRow As Long

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Location list").Range("Dyn_Blend_ID"), Blend_id) > 0 _
    And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Location list").Range("Dyn_LPN_ID"), LPN_id) > 0 Then
    GoTo Start
ElseIf Locate_Lot.Blend_id = "" Then
MsgBox "You did not enter a valid Lot ID", 0, "Check"
Exit Sub
ElseIf Locate_Lot.LPN_id = "" Then
MsgBox "Your LPN is not correct!", 0, "Check LPN"
Exit Sub
End If

Start:

'This is where I'm having issues. If the first column has 2 or more of the same ID, I need it sort 
'to show through them to find the correct ID in the second column and put 
'the information from the second or third, etc. in the information box that comes up.
' Column A has a REF #, The user puts information they want to look for 
'in the input boxes. In column B is the value of the first input box,
'and Column E has the value of the second input box. BUT, if there are 
'two of the same IDs in column B, I need it to sort through those to find 
'and display the information matched to the second input box from column E.

    if not iserror(Application.match(Locate_Lot.LPN_ID, sheets("Location list").range("Dyn_LPN_ID"), 0)) then
    BlendRow = (Application.match(Locate_Lot.LPN_ID, sheets("Location list").range("Dyn_LPN_ID"), 0)
    end if
    'The above is now working, but only matches on the second column, 
    'but I need it to match on both columns from both input boxes of 
    'this Locate_Lot userform.

    '    nxtRow = Sheets("Location list").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    '    For Each srchRow In Sheets("Location list").Range("Dyn_Blend_ID" & nxtRow)
    '    If (srchRow = ("Locate_Lot.Blend_id")) And srchRow.Offset(0, 4).Value = '("Locate_Lot.LPN_id") Then
    '       BlendRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Locate_Lot.LPN_id, Sheets'("Location list").Range("Dyn_LPN_ID"), 0)
    '    End If
    '    Next srchRow

Sheets("Engine").Range("B5").Value = BlendRow
Sheets("Engine").Range("B6").Value = LPNRow

Unload Print_inventory

'''Begin retrieveing data from the Location List'''
Location_Clear.Blend_id = Sheets("Location List").Range("Data_Start").Offset(BlendRow, 1).Value
Location_Clear.Item_id = Sheets("Location List").Range("Data_Start").Offset(BlendRow, 2).Value
Location_Clear.BG_id = Sheets("Location List").Range("Data_Start").Offset(BlendRow, 3).Value
Location_Clear.LPN_id = Sheets("Location List").Range("Data_Start").Offset(BlendRow, 4).Value
Location_Clear.Tower_id = Sheets("Location List").Range("Data_Start").Offset(BlendRow, 5).Value
Location_Clear.Shelf_id = Sheets("Location List").Range("Data_Start").Offset(BlendRow, 6).Value

Location_Clear.Show
```

[Pic of the columns with data entered. Need to match on columns B and E and sort on E giving back that row data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3A5O.png)

Comment: Can you provide more information abuot your data, the current situation, and the desired situation?

Comment: You need to [edit] your post to include the new information.  do not add clarification to the comments.